# Inner join with special conditions

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

Given an hourly table A with full records, e.g.:

```
User    Hour  Purchase 
Joe      1       0
Joe      2       0
Joe      3       0
Joe      4       1
Joe      5       0
Joe      6       0
Joe      7       0
Joe      8       1
Joe      9       1
Joe     10       0
```

And a subset B of it, e.g.

```
User    Hour    Purchase 
Joe      3         0
Joe      9         1
Joe     10         0
```

I want to keep only those records from A that are in B or at most 2hr behind the B subset, without duplication, e.g.

```
User    Hour Purchase 
Joe      1    0
Joe      2    0
Joe      3    0
Joe      7    0
Joe      8    0
Joe      9    1 
Joe     10    0
```

How can the result be achieved with an inner join, without duplication (in this case the hours 8&9) and preserving the right purchase values for the hours in B? (This is an MWE, assume multiple users and timestamps instead of hours)

Comment: is it compulsory to have Left Join? Inner Join will also work here

Comment: also since hour 8 in A will match for the (9 & 10) in B, which one would you like to pick? You mentioned de-duplication, so what's the logic for such condn.

Comment: Agree, inner join is most appropriate here. The logic is to preserve the original value for the hours in B in the de-duplication. The remaining hours (e.g. 8) can pick an arbitrary value in the de-duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple `INNER` join with the proper conditions in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM a INNER JOIN b
ON b.User = a.User AND a.Hour BETWEEN b.Hour - 2 AND b.Hour
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause if you want results for a specific user:

```
WHERE a.User = 'Joe'
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below simple approach

```
select * from tableA a
where exists (
  select 1 from tableB b
  where a.hour between b.hour - 2 and b.hour
  and a.user = b.user
)
```

if applied to sample in your question - output is

[image]

I hope in your real case you have `datetime` or `timestamp` instead of `hour` column, so in this case you will need slightly modify `where a.hour between b.hour - 2 and b.hour` part of above. it will look something like

```
where a.datetime between datetime_sub(b.datetime, interval 2 hour) and b.datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
with _data as 
(
select 'Joe' as _user, 1 as _hour,0 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user, 2 as _hour,0 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user, 3 as _hour,0 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user, 4 as _hour,1 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user, 5 as _hour,0 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user, 6 as _hour,0 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user, 7 as _hour,0 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user, 8 as _hour,1 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user, 9 as _hour,1 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user,10 as _hour,0 as purchase
)
,subset as
(
select 'Joe' as _user, 3 as _hour,0 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user, 9 as _hour,1 as purchase union all
select 'Joe' as _user,10 as _hour,0 as purchase
)
select  a._user,a._hour,any_value(b.purchase) from _data a  join subset b on 
(
    a._user = b._user and 
    (
        a._hour = b._hour 
        or 
        case when b._hour > a._hour then (case when (b._hour - a._hour) <=2 then 1=1 end) end)
)
group by a._user,a._hour
```

Comment: thanks Batra. How is in this solution guaranteed that hour 9 will preserve its purchase=1? Couldn't 0 be picked instead by any_value(b.purchase)?